# python hive client pyhs2 does not recognize 'where' clause in sql statement

Tags: python, sql, client, hive

I am using pyhs2 as hive client. The sql statement with ‘where’ clause was not recognized. Got

> 'pyhs2.error.Pyhs2Exception: 'Error while processing statement:
>
> FAILED: Execution Error,  return code 1 from
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask'

But it runs ok in hive shell.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed! It was due to permission on remote server. Changed user in connect statement from 'root' to 'hdfs' solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was stuck on this for way too long.. so thanks!

Comment: @Kris where did you change this user

Comment: @QasimKhokhar I switched to using `pyspark.sql` a while back, so I don't really remember how this went. You could have a look at `pyhive` too, e.g. `from pyhive import hive; con = hive.connect(..., username=..)`